# Does Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME matter?

Tags: apache-spark

We are running a large Spark application at Amazon Elastic Map Reduce. I've been working hard to remove all WARN messages in the logfile. This is one of two remaining:

```
19/03/21 14:08:09 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
```

Does this matter? If so, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41179711/1138523, if you don't set this, your application will have an overhead during startup which me be delayed some seconds as the jars need to be distributed to the workers. In my opinion no big deal